# Using OpenTBS to create a doc file with php , how to download?

Tags: php, file, download, doc

After reading several articles at SO on how to create a doc file with php i tried the [OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com) with Open Office templates way , because the Fake HTTP Headers way was impossible to style.

I followed the instructions and the script returns me the desired output , altough it doesnt get downloaded . I have no errors in error_log so it must be something else.Anyone who allready uses it could help ?

```
<?php
include JPATH_BASE . DS . 'tbs_class.php';
include JPATH_BASE . DS . 'tbs_plugin_opentbs.php';
$TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
$TBS->LoadTemplate('template.htm');
$method=$_GET['method'];
$id=$_GET['id'];
$teacher=$_GET['teacher'];
$html=DashHelper::getStudentFormForDL($method,$id,$teacher);//returns the html
$output_file_name = 'test.odt';
$message = $html;
$TBS->Show(OPENTBS_DOWNLOAD, $output_file_name);//this should dl the file
exit();
?>
```

Also all the ways i read to create a doc file were from outdated answers. Is there any easier way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You're meant to install the OPENTBS plugin with

```
    $TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);
```

after the

```
    $TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
```